# Concatenate .xlsx files with successive column names in R

Tags: r, concatenation, xlsx

Let's say I have data frames like this:

```
df1 <- as.data.frame(rbind(c(182, 142, 120), c(640, 381, 192)))
colnames(df1) <- c("Q1", "Q2", "Q3")

df2 <- as.data.frame(rbind(c(73, 51, 67, 38), c(62, 42, 33, 46), c(84, 91, 77, 56)))
colnames(df2) <- c("Q4", "Q5", "Q6", "Q7")

df3 <- as.data.frame(t(c(1820, 2114)))
colnames(df3) <- c("Q8", "Q9")

df1
  Q1  Q2  Q3
1 182 142 120
2 640 381 192

df2
  Q4 Q5 Q6 Q7
1 73 51 67 38
2 62 42 33 46
3 84 91 77 56

df3
  Q8   Q9
1 1820 2114
```

Note that I have 3 data frames with different lengths. What I'd like to achieve is a concatenation of one above the other one, indicating its respective column names at doing so.

Desired output:

```
  1 Q1   Q2   Q3
  2 182  142  120
  3 640  381  192
  4 Q4   Q5   Q6   Q7
  5 73   51   67   38
  6 62   42   33   46
  7 84   91   77   56
  8 Q8   Q9
  9 1820 2114
```

I'd been trying to do this first by exporting files to .xlsx then concatenating them, but I only manage to sort of cbind them

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want your desired output in Excel or in R? And what will you then do with this output?

Comment: Please, can you explain the context of your question and your intentions in more detail? I can't imagine what the benefit is to turn tidy data into an "untidy" format. Is just for display? Thank you.

Comment: Right, it's just for display. I know it doesn't seem coherent, hence my problem, but it serves a visual comparison of values of different pools of exon amplifiers of different length. The output would then be used to make some minor calculations in .xlsx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure whether your requested format makes much sense in R, since

1. all elements of a column of a data.frame have to be of the same class, hence will be coerced to character once you add the header lines as rows
2. all rows of a data.frame have to be of the same length, hence you would need to patch the data.frames with less columns with NA columns

But below would be one solution that would give you a data.frame containing the data in the way you showed in your desired output:

```r
df1 <- as.data.frame(rbind(c(182, 142, 120), c(640, 381, 192)))
colnames(df1) <- c("Q1", "Q2", "Q3")

df2 <- as.data.frame(rbind(c(73, 51, 67, 38), c(62, 42, 33, 46), c(84, 91, 77, 56)))
colnames(df2) <- c("Q4", "Q5", "Q6", "Q7")

df3 <- as.data.frame(t(c(1820, 2114)))
colnames(df3) <- c("Q8", "Q9")

maxCol <- max(ncol(df1), ncol(df2), ncol(df3))

match_df <- function(x, ncol){
    delta <- ncol - dim(x)[2]
    out <- {
        if(delta > 0) unname(data.frame(append((rbind(colnames(x), unname(x))), 
            c(rep(NA, delta))))) else 
        unname(data.frame((rbind(colnames(x), unname(x)))))[, seq_len(ncol)]}
    colnames(out) <- paste0("V", seq_len(ncol))
    out
}
out <- unname(do.call(rbind, lapply(list(df1, df2, df3), match_df, ncol=maxCol)))
print(out, na.print = "")
#>                   
#> 1   Q1   Q2  Q3   
#> 2  182  142 120   
#> 3  640  381 192   
#> 4   Q4   Q5  Q6 Q7
#> 5   73   51  67 38
#> 6   62   42  33 46
#> 7   84   91  77 56
#> 8   Q8   Q9       
#> 9 1820 2114
```

A more natural way in R that maintains the numeric data as numeric would be to "sort of cbind them", as you put it, and, if you wish, melt and filter them to remove NA values:

```r
library(data.table)
melt(rbindlist(list(df1, df2, df3), fill=TRUE), na.rm=TRUE)
#>     variable value
#>  1:       Q1   182
#>  2:       Q1   640
#>  3:       Q2   142
#>  4:       Q2   381
#>  5:       Q3   120
#>  6:       Q3   192
#>  7:       Q4    73
#>  8:       Q4    62
#>  9:       Q4    84
#> 10:       Q5    51
#> 11:       Q5    42
#> 12:       Q5    91
#> 13:       Q6    67
#> 14:       Q6    33
#> 15:       Q6    77
#> 16:       Q7    38
#> 17:       Q7    46
#> 18:       Q7    56
#> 19:       Q8  1820
#> 20:       Q9  2114
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this kind of output would be of any help to you but here is a way to do this.

```
#Put the data in a list
list_df <- list(df1, df2, df3)

#Use lapply to iterate over list
output <- lapply(list_df, function(x) {
                   #shift by one row
                   x[2:(nrow(x) + 1), ] <- x
                   #Add column name as 1st row
                   x[1, ] <- names(x)
                   #Make new column names
                   names(x) <- paste0("col", seq_along(x))
                   #return the new dataframes
                   return(x)
           }) %>%  dplyr::bind_rows()
output

#  col1 col2 col3 col4
#1   Q1   Q2   Q3 <NA>
#2  182  142  120 <NA>
#3  640  381  192 <NA>
#4   Q4   Q5   Q6   Q7
#5   73   51   67   38
#6   62   42   33   46
#7   84   91   77   56
#8   Q8   Q9 <NA> <NA>
#9 1820 2114 <NA> <NA>
```